# How to put swig wrappers in a reachable location to be tested by python tests?

Tags: python, cmake, swig

I got a simple test example like this one:

[image]

And my CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

FIND_PACKAGE(SWIG REQUIRED)
INCLUDE(${SWIG_USE_FILE})

FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH})

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

SET(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS "")

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(example.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
set(SWIG_MODULE_example_EXTRA_DEPS example.cxx example.h)
SWIG_ADD_MODULE(example python example.i example.cxx)
SWIG_LINK_LIBRARIES(example ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

After generating the ST files and building the wrapper I'll get this output in the build directory:

[image]

Problem here is my test `runme.py` isn't able to load those libraries. So, my question is, how can I place the `example.py` and `example.pyd` (only those ones) to be in a reachable place to be tested properly? I've tried adding this line to the CMakeLists.txt `set(CMAKE_SWIG_OUTDIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/..)` and the result was placing the .py and the generated wrappers alone:

[image]

And the .pyd remaining in the build folder:

[image]

So, how can I put the wrappers in a reachable place to be tested by my python test files?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to import the libraries into your runme.py. In order to import python files in a sub-directory, that sub-directory needs an __init__.py file in it. You can place an empty one into your build folder. This should allow your program to import the files.

You could then use:

```
import build.example
import build._example
```

This way it wouldn't matter if the files aren't in the same directory, assuming that there is not another reason you want them there.

Edit:

Since the build folder doesn't exist ahead of time you can always create and compile the __init__.py file in the runme.py file by doing:

```
import os
import py_compile

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
open(dir_path + os.sep + "build" + os.sep + "__init__.py", "w+")
py_compile.compile(dir_path + os.sep + "build" + os.sep + "__init__.py")
py_compile.compile(dir_path + os.sep + "build" + os.sep + "example.py")

import build.example
import build._example
```

This will create the file you need and then be able to do the import without using CMake.

Comment: Sure, I'm aware of that. In any case, do you know how to generate the __init__ file when invoking CMake? I'd prefer avoid typing any custom command (touch __init__.py) outside CMake, ie: the process being perfectly driven by CMake alone

Comment: Sorry I didnt know you didn't have the build folder ahead of time. I edited my answer to generate the file you need to do the import from within the runme.py file, so it shouldn't require anything to be done in CMake or any outside intervention.

Answer (score 0):

I use C++ for unit testing and Python for testing against reference implementations or integration testing.

The approach I use is to add a custom target, which copies the libraries as well as any extra generated files to my source directory, where the python test files are located. I have configured my `.gitignore` file such that they are never added by mistake to my repository.

```
add_custom_target(copy ALL)

# Some library my Swig wrapped library depends on (say gl)
add_custom_command(TARGET copy
  PRE_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy $<TARGET_FILE:gl> ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  DEPENDS $<TARGET_FILE:gl>)

# The Swig library, say swig_example (Note the _ in the target name)
add_custom_command(TARGET copy
  PRE_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different $<TARGET_FILE:_swig_example> ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  DEPENDS $<TARGET_FILE:_swig_example>)

# The extra .py files generated by SWIG
add_custom_command(TARGET copy
  PRE_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${swig_extra_generated_files} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  DEPENDS $<TARGET_FILE:_swig_example>)

enable_testing()

add_test(
  NAME    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/some_test.py"
  COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/some_test.py
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

I believe this is a very neat setup. Alternatively, you could start adding paths in your Python test scripts, but it is often desired to support an arbitrary build location.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the structure of your `some_test.py` file and how tied in to the source tree it is, but I guess I'm curious why you couldn't instead have CMake copy the _test_ into the _build_ tree (e.g. `configure_file(some_test.py some_test.py COPYONLY)`), and then run the test from there (using `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` instead of `..._SOURCE_...`) instead of polluting your source tree with build files. (This would also allow you to maintain multiple build directories, without them trampling each other's generated SWIG bindings in the source tree.)

Comment: For testing, I often use a hierarchy of files, which includes several packages. I usually configure git to know not to start adding generated files